# How to use Git directly when edit DDL in DataGrip？

Tags: git, datagrip

[image: I only could use Local History when I use DDL, Git Option is gray]

How could I use git to VCS when I use DDL ?

Comment: You can add objects to git from files view: https://i.imgur.com/HvJ5l7w.png

Comment: Database objects are not files, so could not be added to VCS

Comment: Database objects in DataGrip could map to local by DDL Source Mapping, but still could not use Git.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot use Git'? Do you see it under the menu?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment DataGrip can't store database in version control.

Follow a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3852/Database-in-version-control) in DataGrip bug tracker to get updates.